# Displaying data on Full Calendar using Ajax not displaying records

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-core

I have created a Full Calendar and using ajax to populate the events from a database tables.

I can get the graph showing however it isn't populating the events from the database, instead it is showing todays date and time and only one event.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I'm following this tutorial:
http://www.dotnetawesome.com/2017/06/event-calendar-in-aspnet-mvc.html

What is 
[currently displaying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPZGe.png)

> Script which is in my Layout page

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var events = [];
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Calendar/Schedules",
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (i, v) {
                    events.push({
                        title: v.Subject,
                        description: v.Description,
                        start: moment(v.Start),
                        end: v.EndTime != null ? moment(v.EndTime) : null,
                        color: v.ThemeColor,
                        allDay: v.IsFullDay
                    });
                })

                GenerateCalender(events);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert('failed');
            }
        })
        function GenerateCalender(events) {
            $('#calender').fullCalendar('destroy');
            $('#calender').fullCalendar({
                contentHeight: 400,
                defaultDate: new Date(),
                timeFormat: 'h(:mm)a',
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay,agenda'
                },
                eventLimit: true,
                eventColor: '#378006',
                events: events

            })
        }
    });
</script>
```

> Get method under the Calendar Controller

```
public JsonResult Schedules()
        {
            var schedules = _context.Schedules.ToList();
            var result = new JsonResult(new { Data = schedules});
           return new JsonResult(result.Value);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> however it isn't populating the events from the database

1. Note that you're following an old tutorial for *ASP.NET Classic* instead of *ASP.NET Core*. And the way we return a `JsonResult` has **changed**:

   ```
   public JsonResult Schedules()
   {
       var schedules = _context.Schedules.ToList();
       var result = new JsonResult(new { Data = schedules});
       return new JsonResult(result.Value);
       return new JsonResult(schedules);
   }
   ```

   Today we don't need specifiy a `Data` property for `JsonResult` anymore. Instead, simply construct a `JsonResult` by `new JsonResult(the_data)`.
2. The second issue is, the returned json by default is **Camel-Cased** if you're using ASP.NET Core 3.1. However, it's likely that your javascript code assumes that the JSON returned by server is **Pascal-Cased**. If that's the case, change your js code as below:

   ```
   events.push({
       title: v.Subject,
       title: v.subject,
       description: v.Description,
       description: v.description,
       start: moment(v.Start),
       start: moment(v.start),
       end: v.EndTime != null ? moment(v.EndTime) : null,
       end: v.endTime != null ? moment(v.endTime) : null,
       color: v.ThemeColor,
       color: v.themeColor,
       allDay: v.IsFullDay
       allDay: v.isFullDay
   });
   ```